# Solution of first order non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I'm trying to prove that the ode
$$
x'(t)=5\cos^2(tx)-x^2-5, \ \ \ x(t_0)=x_0
$$
has strictly decreasing solutions for $x_0\neq 0$. The problem is that i only find the solution $x(t)=0$. It also says that for $t_0=1,x_0=0$ the Cauchy problem has unique solution wich doesn't make sense since i can't find any other solution than 0. Any ideas?

Comment: To check if $x$ is strictly decreasing, just check the derivatives.

Comment: Did you try with $z=tx$ ?

Comment: Is it $\cos(tx)^2$ or $\cos^2(tx)$?

Comment: It's $cos^2(tx)$

Answer (score 1):

The ODE is of the form
$$
x'(t)=-x(t)^2-5\sin^2(tx(t))=-x(t)^2g(t,x(t))
$$
with a smooth function $g$. This implies that the zero solution separates the solution space. No other solution can take the value zero. For all other solutions the right side is strictly negative.

Comment: The smoothness of $g$ also proves that for $t_0=1, x_0=0$ there exits a unique solution? I feel like i should apply Picard's theorem.

Comment: You can directly confirm that $x(t)=0$ is a solution of the ODE. The smoothness provides the uniqueness, so that no other solution may cross it.